# Python Grabbing String in between characters

Tags: python

If I have a string like /*Hello how are you*/, how am I supposed to grab this line and delete it using a python script.

```
import sys
import re

i_file = sys.argv[1];

def stripwhite(text):
    lst = text.split('"')
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if not i % 2:
            lst[i] = re.sub("\s+", "", item)
    return '"'.join(lst)

with open(i_file) as i_file_comment_strip:

        i_files_names = i_file_comment_strip.readlines()

        for line in i_files_names:
                with open(line, "w") as i_file_data:
                        i_file_comment = i_file_data.readlines();
                        for line in i_file_comment:
                                i_file_comment_data = i_file_comment.strip()
```

In the i_file_comment I have the lines from i_file_data and i_file_comment contains the lines with the "/*...*/" format. Would I use a for loop through each character in the line and replace every one of those characters with a ""?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete sample input/structure?

Comment: Please can you re-write the question so it makes sense? And submit a sample input / desired output.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I apologize for not explaining the problem in a clear manner. I actually found out my problem now, but thank you for providing your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the */Hello how are you/* you can use regex:

```
import re
x = 'some text /Hello how are you/ some more text'
print (re.sub(r'/.*/','', x))
```

Output:

```
some text  some more text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have occurences of a fixed string in your lines, you can simply do

```
for line in i_file_comment:
    line = line.replace('/Hello how are you/', '')
```

however, if what you have is multiple occurences of strings delimited by `/` (i.e. /foo/, /bar/), I think using a simple regex will sufice:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\/[\w\s]+\/')
>>> s = """
... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
... /Hello how are you/ ++ tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
... /Hello world/ -- ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
... """
>>> print re.sub(regex, '', s)  # find substrings matching the regex, replace them with '' on string s

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 ++ tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 -- ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo

>>>
```

just adjust the regex to what you need to get rid of :)